# Load external data to google maps and build heatmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my database I have set of zip codes and number of orders for specific zip code

```
zip    | count
--------------
12-456 |   23
12-100 |  120
12-220 |   93
10-300 |    2
```

I need a way to show that data as heat map using GoogleMaps.
I found basic example at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap 
It is a nice start, but it requires me to add all the points to my page.

Is there an option to show page and then do request to server to get all the points?
I know that I can make ajax request to server, get json as result and then in loop add those point to `taxiData` (code from example), but maybe this can be done easier?
In Poland are almost 23 thousands zip codes, so I can have very large dataset from server.

Is it possible to load data as `latitude, longitude, count`?
I can convert zip codes to locations (GPS coordinates) but I would like to send number of orders in that location.

How can I show heat map for specific region? Like in this sample: http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_customTiles.html heat map is only presented for United States.

Any ideas on how to start (links, examples) are big help.

Answer (score 1):

First question:
Well just a thought, you could sample the zip codes and let the user choose the detail. If he wants more detail it will take a little more to load. In low map zooms you don't need that many points. If the user wants more detail in higher map zooms you fetch more. But don't underestimate ajax, I had a web site page that loaded around 9000 database entries and it was ready in around 3 secs, maybe less. Just don't block the page and don't forget to use a loader :)

Second question:
In SQL you could do

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, COUNT(*) count FROM Table GROUP BY latitude, longitude
```

This will give you the unique pairs of latitude and longitude and their count. If you want you could play with the decimal points to get more or less accuracy.

Third question:
That map uses MCustomTileLayer. You can see and download the source code here http://code.google.com/p/biodiversity-imageserver/source/browse/trunk/unittest/gmap3/MCustomTileLayer.js?r=49

That site's example:

```
var hMap = new MCustomTileLayer(map,theme);

var oDiv = document.getElementById('controlsDiv');
var tlcOptions = {
    parent: oDiv,
    overlay: hMap,
    caption: theme.toUpperCase()
}
var tlc = new MTileLayerControl(tlcOptions);
```

To be honest I prefer a lot more the standard google API, its simpler and prettier. They just produce an image and place it on the map. You can play with the heatmap radius to fill just the zones you want.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for tips, right now I'm in process of developing demo for my presentation. One more question about details level. How can I group it? Probably using server-side, but I don't know how to combine it with Google Maps. Should I use zoom event and then load new data from server? Could You explain that bit more?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you could define a number of points per zoom level. So for low zooms you could sample them or interpolate them or just use the average, it might depend on the application (those techniques are used in a similar way in image processing). For high zoom you could just get the original points, one thing you have to do is to see the bounds of the map (there's an API for that too) and only fetch the points that the user is viewing, so you had to do it on zoom and on padding.

Comment: I done something similar in an android application because at the time there wasn't an API for heatmaps so i did it by drawing layers on padding and zoom and it became a bit non responsive cause it involved a few (...) calculations but it worked alright. It depends on what you want, the drawings on the map a bit laggy or a high initial loading time. If I were you i would try both and see what i liked the best. Depends if the users are going to use high zoom levels often too.

Comment: Btw just a thought you could also have the levels with the necessary points already defined on the database and only fetch the ones the user is viewing using the map bounds and the level by the zoom level, instead calculating every time.